# SSAS error message in Excel when adding new dimension

Tags: excel-2010, ssas

I have a cube in SSAS that work well. I access the cube via Excel/connection and create a pivot table.

But when I add one new specific dimension into it I am having problem:
As soon as that new dimension is in the cube, I can still create a new connection to it, but when I close the file and reopen it I got the following message:
"Excel encountered unreadable content in [filename.xlsx]."
Then the connection doesn't work anymore and the pivottable is empty, we have to recreate the connection and the pivot table... all working well until we close the file.

I tested it and the issu is only there when I add that dimension.
Since the error message is useless and I can't figure out what is the cause of the problem, I am asking you guys.

Any idea what it could be ?
Do you have a list of things to check?

Any help would be appreciate, thank you

Comment: I found a post regarding your problem. It will may be helps you. Let me know https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/the_microsoft_excel_support_team_blog/2012/11/15/pivot-table-stripped-after-unreadable-content-error-encountered/

Comment: Thank you, it is exactly the issue I have, but the workaround is not the solution for me as the pivot table is empty anyway.

Comment: I removed one by one the column/attribute from the dimension to see if and what attribute is causing the issue and I found it and removed it, even if I do not understand why it is cause an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed one by one the column/attribute from the dimension to see if and what attribute is causing the issue and I found it and removed it, even if I do not understand why it is cause an issue.